# How to disable email alerts for specific/single document library

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, document-library, alert, sharepoint-email

We have email alerts on document library which send email to users after new document has been added. But we want to disable email alerts on this **single document library** only. How to achieve this?

Thank you.

Comment: is it onprem or online ?

Comment: its on-premises.

Answer (score 0):

You'd have to delete the existing alerts for all the users and then create a custom permission level that disallows them to create alerts. The permission level will be unique.

Something like (excerpt from [here](http://www.sharepointdiary.com/2015/07/disable-alerts-on-sharepoint-2013-list-using-powershell.html)):

```
Function Disable-ListAlerts($WebURL, $ListName)

{

    #Get the Web and List objects

    $Web = Get-SPWeb $WebURL

    $List = $web.Lists.TryGetList($ListName)



    #Get All Alerts created in the list - Which are Active

    $ListAlerts = $Web.Alerts | Where-Object {($_.List.Title -eq $List.Title) -and ($_.Status -eq "ON")}



    Write-host "Total Number of Active Alerts Found in the list: $($ListAlerts.Count)"



    #Iterate through each alert and turn it OFF

    foreach($Alert in $ListAlerts)

        {

            $Alert.Status="OFF"

            $Alert.Update()

            write-host "Disabled the Alert' $($Alert.Title)' Created for User '$($Alert.User.Name)'"

        }



    #Dispose web object

    $Web.Dispose()

}
```

Then create a custom permission level that unchecks "Create Alerts", then switch everyone to that new permission level(s).